# JSF Trouble with beans (scope)

Tags: jsf, session, scope, request, javabeans

So I was testing my JSF application and suddenly I can't pull the value I stored in the bean anymore.  I switched from Request scope to Session scope and I was able to pull a value, but it seems to be the value of the last page I clicked.

File structure goes something like this:
About.xhtml sets a page number stored on the Bean and then calls Layout.xhtml which calls Bean.Method() to get Content_About.xhtml to load some text to the page depending on the page number declared in the About.xhtml file.

To my understanding the Request scope should work as long as I don't need to access the stored information past the page loading, but it is acting as if the page number hasn't been set.

With a Session scope declared, it loads the text, but it seems as if it is building the page, then changing the stored value in the bean.  It requires that I click on the page I want twice to get the correct information on a page.

Any help appreciated.

Further investigation:  I am able to do the following, but it shows the correct page number before and after the method call to load the content.

```
Page Number: #{MainBean.getPage()}
<h:form>
<ui:include src="#{MainBean.Content()}"></ui:include>
</h:form>
Page Number: #{MainBean.getPage()}
```

Comment: I'm using Netbeans (IDE 6.9.1) and glassfish 3 to deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accepting that the ui is built first, using the default value of the stored variable, I proceeded to set the value in the ui declaration when layout is called.

I had something like:

```
#{MainBean.setLevel(0)}
#{MainBean.setPage(1)}
<ui:include src="Layout.xhtml"></ui:include>
```

and changed it to:

```
    <ui:include src="#{MainBean.setLayout(0,1)}"></ui:include>

public String setLayout(int lvl, int pg)
    {
        setLevel(lvl);
        setPage(pg);

        return GetPath()+"Layout.xhtml";
    }
```

This allows the bean's variable to be set during the construction of the ui and carry forward through the rest of the request.